# E-commerce website to Google Cloud database

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

How does cloud pubsub receive user activities on a e-commerce website?. Is the endpoint going to be a URL or an IP address and a port

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more details to your question. Are you trying to send Pub/Sub messages to an e-commerce website, or from it? What e-commerce website are you attempting to use? What's the overall problem?

Comment: I'm try to receive real time event from an e-commerce website to cloud pubsub

Answer (score 0):

On [this graph](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#concepts) you can see the workflow. You will need your app or your service to [publish a message](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publishing_messages) to the Pub/Sub topic which will then the topic will [pass to a subscriber via Pull or Push](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber).

To publish a message you can call a URL like

"http s://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/topics/mytopic:publish" as mentioned on [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publishing_messages)
or  with the help of a Client library wich will need you to call a method, fo example in NodeJS it will be somehting like

```
const messageId = await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);
console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
```

that is also described on the docs mentioned before.

I'm not really getting the use of Pub/Sub since it will be better if you explained your arquitecture and use case, but for example here is a quick [architecture model on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/architecture/scaling-commerce-workloads-architecture)